# Embedded Influx doesn't work on mac os

Tags: influxdb

I use embedded influx https://github.com/APISENSE/embed-influxDB version 1.1.1. I use the following code snippet to start embedded influx on mac os 10.12.6

```
val builder = new InfluxServer.Builder
freeServerPort = Network.getFreeServerPort
val influxConfig = new InfluxConfigurationWriter.Builder().setHttp(freeServerPort).build
builder.setInfluxConfiguration(influxConfig)
server = builder.build
server.start()
Thread.sleep(10 * 1000)
InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://" + EMBEDDED_INFLUX_HOST + ":" + freeServerPort)
```

Every time I try to run it I get the following message:

> [influxd error]/var/folders/z6/zxktn8v10nx_ssb1zctm_5w80000gn/T/extract-c9d95ee0-f9fb-4387-bb94-e85806f45c21influxd: /var/folders/z6/zxktn8v10nx_ssb1zctm_5w80000gn/T/extract-c9d95ee0-f9fb-4387-bb94-e85806f45c21influxd: cannot execute binary file
>   [influxd error]

Comment: This actually is not an embedded InfluxDB. It downloads and installs the actual influxDB in the background.  Did you get any alternative for it?

Comment: Actually not. I wanted this embedded influx db for testing purposes. Since influxdb uses http protocol for queries, I mocked up http requests and checked that correct query comes.